# Error converting data type varchar to numeric but ISNUMERIC = 1

Tags: t-sql

I'm going crazy here. Can someone help me understand why the first query below returns data successfully, but the second query (where all that was changed was moving the logic in the case statement to the WHERE clause) fails with an "error converting varchar to numeric"?  If it works as part of the results set, why wouldn't it work in the where clause?

Query 1:

```
SELECT  ASSESSMENT
       ,PENALTY
       ,CASE WHEN ( CAST(ASSESSMENT AS NUMERIC(14, 2)) * .06 ) < CAST(PENALTY AS NUMERIC(14,2)) 
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END
FROM    TABLES
```

Query 2:

```
   SELECT  ASSESSMENT
           ,PENALTY
    FROM    TABLES
    WHERE   ( CAST(ASSESSMENT AS NUMERIC(14, 2)) * .06 ) < CAST(PENALTY AS NUMERIC(14,2))
```

I've also checked with an ISNUMERIC on the two columns and everything = 1.  I also gave TRY_CONVERT a shot and all values were successfully converted, so in my mind it should all work correctly.

EDIT: Screenshots for briskovich

[image: Working Screenshot]
[image: Failed Screenshot]

Comment: I can not reproduce your error. Could you reproduce your error with some sample data here? https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: You could try out try_convert. If is fails it will just return NULL and not raise an error. This could help you track down the value that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with doing this?

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  ASSESSMENT
       ,PENALTY
       ,CASE WHEN ( CAST(ASSESSMENT AS NUMERIC(14, 2)) * .06 ) < CAST(PENALTY AS NUMERIC(14,2)) 
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END [CALC FIELD]
FROM    TABLES
)t 
WHERE [CALC FIELD] = 1
```

Comment: See, this is what I can't figure out.  That fails too.  Anything that touches either [ASSESSMENT] or [PENALTY] causes an error.  It makes zero sense to me.

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.  Added screenshots.

Comment: You must have characters in those columns that are not numbers. Clean up the data in those columns and everything should run properly.